# (kohana) Unittest DbUnit foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, kohana, dbunit

I've searched through google/stackoverflow for a solution but failed to find a satisfying solution.

My issue:

```
[SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a
foreign key constraint (integration.b_node_leafs, CONSTRAINT fk_node_id
FOREIGN KEY (node_id) REFERENCES integration.b_nodes (id))]
```

And I can't find anywhere in the docs who to solve this issue neither a order for the XmlDataSet (which  I use).

This doesn't work.

```
public function setUp() {
  $conn=$this->getConnection();
  $conn->getConnection()->query("set foreign_key_checks=0");
  parent::setUp();
  $conn->getConnection()->query("set foreign_key_checks=1");
}
```

Results in mysql.log

```
Connect         root@localhost on integration_db
Query           set foreign_key_checks=0
Connect         root@localhost on integration_db
Query           TRUNCATE `table_name`
Quit
Quit
```

This is my dataset.xml (As you can see I start from the bottom).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
  <!-- Meta for node -->
  <b_meta id="4321" created_by="###NULL###" deleted="0" />
  <!-- Meta for leaf -->
  <b_meta id="1010" created_by="###NULL###" deleted="0" />
  <!-- Meta for post -->
  <b_meta id="1050" created_by="###NULL###" deleted="0" />
  <!-- meta for comment -->
  <b_meta id="7894" created_by="###NULL###" deleted="0" />

  <!-- Add comment -->
  <b_comments id="5555" meta_id="7894" text="This is a integrationtest" />
  <!-- Add Post -->
  <b_posts id="4646" meta_id="1050" title="How to integration" seo_title="how-to-integration" text="Explain why to use integrationtests" />
  <!-- Link comment to post -->
  <b_post_comments post_id="4646" comment_id="5555" />
  <!-- Add Leaf -->
  <b_leafs id="3535" meta_id="1010" title="App Testing" seo_title="app-testing" />
  <!-- Link leaf to post -->
  <b_leaf_posts leaf_id="3535" post_id="4646" />
  <!-- Add node -->
  <b_nodes id="1234" meta_id="4321" type="forum" title="PHP" />
  <!-- Link node to leaf -->
  <b_node_leafs node_id="1234" leaf_id="3535" />
</dataset>
```

PS: I run on PHPUnit 3.7.28

Comment: That's a MySQL limitation that you can only work around by dropping and re-creating the foreign keys as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to save the connection for multiple uses instead of creating new connection for each operation.

In your test setUp function add

```
public function setUp()
{
  $conn = $this->getConnection();
  $conn->getConnection()->query("set foreign_key_checks=0");
  return parent::setUp();
}
```

In Kohana_Unittest_Database_TestCase

```
protected $_connection;
public function getConnection()
{
  if ($this->_connection !== NULL)
  {
    return $this->_connection;
  }

  // Get the unittesting db connection
  $config = Kohana::$config->load('database.'.$this->_database_connection);

  if(strtolower($config['type']) !== 'pdo')
  {
    $config['connection']['dsn'] = strtolower($config['type']).':'.
      'host='.$config['connection']['hostname'].';'.
      'dbname='.$config['connection']['database'];
  }

  $pdo = new PDO(
    $config['connection']['dsn'], 
$config['connection']['username'], 
$config['connection']['password']
  );

  $this->_connection = $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, $config['connection']['database']);

  return $this->_connection;
}
```

See my pull request: https://github.com/kohana/unittest/pull/36